# Central Limit Theorem and Moment Generating Functions?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, moments, moment-generating-function

One can identify identical distributions by the equality of their Moment Generating Function (MGF), if it exists.

Let's say $X_i$ ($i>0$) are independent random variables drawn from an identical distribution with mean $u$ and finite variance $s^2$

Let $Z=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dotsm+X_N$

As $N$ gets larger we know that the distribution $Z$ ought to converge to a normal distribution with mean $Nu$ and variance $Ns^2$ by the Central Limit Theorem ***for Sums***

(see: https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/MA121-4.1.2.pdf www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/370/408clt.pdf)

I suppose it must be the case that:

$MGF(Z)=MGF(X_1+X_2+X_3\space+\dotsm+X_N)$

And since $Z$ is approximately normal for large $N$, I'd guess that $MGF(Z)$ is also approximately a normal MGF.

Moreover, the MGF of the sum of independent variables is the product of their individual MGFs so it seems we can say that, as  N gets large, the following holds? :

Normal MGF with mean $nu$ and variance $ns^2$ $\approx[MGF(X_1)]^n$

$e^{nut+(1/2)ns^2t^2}\approx[MGF(X_1)]^N$

And this ought to work for any distribution then? So the MGF of any distribution ought to approach the normal MGF if one raises it to a large enough $N$?

I graphed a Normal MGF (red), Poisson MGF raised to $N$ (purple) and Uniform (over $[0,1]$) MGF raised to $N$ (black) here ($t$ on the $x$-axis): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kmgpzs3vq9

All have mean and variance of unity.

They SEEM to be converging when $t>=0$ but this does not seem to be the case when $t$ is very negative, so what am I doing wrong?

Note that I have not been able to show that the limit as $N$ tends to infinity of the difference between the normal MGF and any arbitrary MGF raised to $N$ is zero (nor am I sure if this is a result I should expect).

Comment: "*As N gets larger we know that the distribution Z ought to converge to a normal distribution with mean Nu and variance Ns2 by the Central Limit Theorem.*" -- well, no, that's not right. You should check what the central limit theorem actually says. It's about the distribution of standardized means (or equivalently, standardized sums) converging to a standard normal in the limit.

Comment: www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/370/408clt.pdf

https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/MA121-4.1.2.pdf

I do believe it is right?

Comment: Kannot, not everything posted on the Web is correct or even clear, even when it might come from academia.  You have found a good example of a reference that would be better to ignore.  If you want to do rigorous mathematics then (1) focus on the standardized mean, because it has a chance of having a limiting distribution and (2) use the characteristic function rather than the mgf, because the cf always exists and it determines the distribution.

Comment: "central limit theorem of sums": you won't find any serious sources for your assertion. to understand this, just check that the normal distribution to which $Z$ would converge is degenerated (the variance as well as the mean would go to infinity  as $N$ gets larger). The central limit theorem is an asymptotical results which states that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Z$ converges in distribution to a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$-variable. of course it follows that for large $n$ you have $Z$ is **approx.** $N(N\mu,N\sigma^2)$, but this alone is not helpful enough to derive theoretical results.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should see what comes out of defining Z as the sample mean instead of the sums.

Comment: Commenting twice by mistake, I still don't see why one does not atleast visually see the graphs for the MGFs "come closer" for increasing Ns though. Even if theoretically no meaningful claims can be made.

Comment: The graphs *do* converge *provided you standardize them.* This amounts to multiplying them by $e^{-nut}$ and replacing $t$ by $t/\sqrt{n}$.